# Ошибка в коде js

Tags: javascript

Файл js подключен перед закрывающим тегом body

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) +1 ;

var guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
var lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrrHi');

var guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.quessSubmit');
var guessField = document.querySelector('.quessField');

var quessCount = 1;                                         
var resetButton;

function checkGuess() {
    alert('I am a placeholder');
}

function checkGuess() {
  var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);

  if (guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';

  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if (guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = '!!!GAME OVER!!!';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
    } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
    }
  }

  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();
}

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);

function setGameOver() {
    guessField.disabled = true;
    guessSubmit.disabled = true;
    resetButton = document.createElement('button');
    resetButton.textContent = 'Start new game';
    document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
}
function resetGame() {
    guessCount = 1;
    const resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < resetParas.length ; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
}
resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
guessField.disabled = false;
guessSubmit.disabled = false;
guessField.value = '';
guessField.focus();
lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
```

Так же html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Number guessing game</title>

    <style>
      html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      body {
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 800px;
        min-width: 480px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .lastResult {
        color: white;
        padding: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Number guessing game</h1>

    <p>We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or fewer. We'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.</p>

    <div class="form">
      <label for="guessField">Enter a guess: </label><input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
      <input class="guessSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit guess">
    </div>

    <div class="resultParas">
      <p class="guesses"></p>
      <p class="lastResult"></p>
      <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Сама ошибка:

[image: Вот пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может потому что не `quessSubmit` а `guessSubmit`

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) +1 ;

var guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
var lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrrHi');

var guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
var guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');

var quessCount = 1;                                         
var resetButton;

function checkGuess() {
    alert('I am a placeholder');
}

function checkGuess() {
  var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);

  if (guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';

  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if (guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = '!!!GAME OVER!!!';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Wrong!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
    } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
    }
  }

  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();
}

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);

function setGameOver() {
    guessField.disabled = true;
    guessSubmit.disabled = true;
    resetButton = document.createElement('button');
    resetButton.textContent = 'Start new game';
    document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
}
function resetGame() {
    guessCount = 1;
    const resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < resetParas.length ; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
}
resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
guessField.disabled = false;
guessSubmit.disabled = false;
guessField.value = '';
guessField.focus();
lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
```

```css
html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      body {
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 800px;
        min-width: 480px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .lastResult {
        color: white;
        padding: 3px;
      }
```

```html
    <h1>Number guessing game</h1>

    <p>We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or fewer. We'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.</p>

    <div class="form">
      <label for="guessField">Enter a guess: </label><input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
      <input class="guessSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit guess">
    </div>

    <div class="resultParas">
      <p class="guesses"></p>
      <p class="lastResult"></p>
      <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
    </div>
```